# Resharper 8.1 - generate a variable from method definition

Tags: resharper

Say I have a C# method `DoSomething(SomeClass param)` and I've written the following:

`DoSomething(`

Is there a shortcut that will produce:

`var someClass = new SomeClass();`

`DoSomething(someClass)`

The classes I have don't support initializers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the **Introduce Variable** refactoring that will show up when you use the undeclared `someClass` variable name. Simply type it as-is, and when the code is red, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and use said refactoring to create such a variable. Its initialization is, of course, your responsibility.

Comment: That only creates the variable but does not initialise it, i.e. it only creates `SomeClass someClass;`

Comment: Yep. Just type the = and you can initialize it or use smart completion (Shift+Alt+Space) for suggestions.